# "Ни сном ни духом" - с запятой или без запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

Сейчас полазил по сайтам и нашел несколько примеров из художественной литературы у известных авторов, и у всех по-разному.

... (,) ни сном(,) ни духом (,) ...

...(,) ни сном ни духом (,)...

... ни сном(,) ни духом...

... ни сном  ни духом...

Я так понял, что четких правил по этому вопросу  нет, и поэтому запятые можно ставить факультативно ?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: ни сном ни духом (не разделяется запятыми и не обособляется).

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Сочетание "ни сном ни духом" выступает как устойчивая единица со значением одного слова: не знает ни сном ни духом - это не знает абсолютно (ни на волос,  вовсе,  ничуть,  нисколечко, совсем, в полном смысле слова, совершенно).

Например:

"Плотники клялись, что они ни сном ни духом не ведают, куда девались книги ― они не брали" (Василий Шукшин).

2) В предложении "ни сном ни духом" обычно является обстоятельством степени, тесно связано с глаголом и не обособляется. Иногда глагол, к которому относится сочетание,  пропускается, что обозначается с помощью тире:

А деревня про их шашни ― ни сном ни духом.

Они ― ни сном ни духом.

Comment: Вера, но в тоже время у классиков встречается и с запятой. Ср.: Он тут ни сном, ни духом не виноват.. . И. А. Гончаров, «Обрыв».( Ефремова) Он тут ни сном ни духом не виноват (Гончаров. Обрыв). Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка. — М.: Астрель, АСТ А. И. Фёдоров 2008

Comment: Кто виноват - редакторы? Ведь по правилам запятая не нужна.

Comment: У Гончарова по современным нормам запятая не нужна, но также, я думаю,  возможна авторская пунктуация, когда выражение в распространенном предложении понимается дословно, внутренняя связь ослабевает и запятая ставится, например: "Но в данный момент Отон был к этому не причастен ни сном, ни духом и сам задумчиво чесал затылок". Ни сном, ни духом не чаял он, что этот полумертвый барин, Иван Иванович Михельсон, чрез полтора десятка лет станет самым упорным, самым назойливым и неотступным врагом Емельяна Пугачева (В. Я. Шишков).

Comment: Да, скорее так, вы правы.